# How can I change mouse pointer icon on a web page?

Tags: javascript, icons, hover, mouse, html

Is there any way to change mouse pointer icon using javascript(or any other method) when I hover it on a normal text on which I want it to appear like a hand as with links on a webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Using css:

> div { cursor:pointer; }

Answer (score 1):

Look up the css attribute [cursor](http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm).

It's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use like:

```
onmouseover="this.style.cursor = 'hand';"  //on mouse over
onmouseout="this.style.cursor = 'auto';"  // on mouse out
```